# Mailgun - Modify and/or wrap unsubscribe page

Tags: mailgun, unsubscribe

I'm using the Mailgun unsubscribe handling.  I'd like to be able modify the mailgun generated "Unsubscribe" and "You have unsubscribed" pages.  If there is no way to modify these pages, is there a way to wrap them with header / footer to add some branding?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, unless you handle the unsubscribes on your server, there is no way to customise those pages!

Answer (score 1):

Hey You can actually handle it yourself. What your saying is possible however according to mail-gun support the urls are never front facing meaning in your html you would have to do something like this:

```
<br>
 Want to change how you receive these emails?<br>
<a href=%mailing_list_unsubscribe_url% target="_blank">Stop receiving emails 
from us</a><br>
&nbsp;
```

According to them this should work the same as there methods. if you do not want to use the unsubscribe mailing list then use another one there are 3 [found here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#tracking-unsubscribes)

Answer (score 0):

According to Mailgun support, there is no such option yet. But you can create a custom unsubscribe page on your server and link it to the unsubscribe button in your email. Thereafter you can unsubscribe the user from your domain or your mailing list by using [Mailgun API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-suppressions.html#unsubscribes).